# MYSQL create record for each month between two dates

Tags: mysql, loops, period

I have two dates (start_date and end_date). I am trying to create one record for each month between those two dates.

As an example:

```
start_date= 01/01/2016
end_date=23/04/2016
```

Output:

```
Period
2016-01-31
2016-02-28
2016-03-31
2016-04-30
```

I am fairly new to mysql and not sure how to achieve that. Could you please give me some ideas?

thanks

Comment: use between syntax --> WHERE [datecolumn] BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Comment: Hi thanks but what is the query to insert a line for each month between those 2 dates?

Comment: 4/30 is not between those two dates.

Comment: Hi, sorry my request was not so clear. i would need to include the actual month of the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select Date_Sub(Date_Add('2015/01/01',INTERVAL 1 Month),INTERVAL 1 Day)
```

I guess you want to print end date of month between two intervals, Use above statement in your loop.

Comment: thanks for that. actually i need help with the loop too :)